# Create pandas dataframe from lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 lists:

`list_1 = [1,2,3]`

`list_2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`

`list_3 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]`

I want to get the follwoing dataframe:

```
     co1   col2  col3
0     1     a      a1
1     2     b      a2
2     3     c      a3
3     NaN   d      a4
4     NaN   e      NaN
5     NaN   f      NaN
```

I tried the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : list_1,
"col2" : list_2,
"col3" : list_3,})
```

I got the error: `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

I want a method to take the max of lists length as the dataframe size and fill missing values with `NaN`

I appreciate any help from your side

Comment: Thanks for closing the question, unfortunately I find that the answer is not available in questions you referred. Thanks to ChatGPT I got the custom code, I thinl SO is getting poor over the time, thanks any way for previous helps provided. Next time I will ask directly ChatGPT instead of wasting my precious time with you